# google apps script Xmlservice

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

I'm updating some code that used to use `Xml.parse` to parse this page https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&CIK=&type=8-k&owner=exclude&count=100&action=getcurrent

The old code uses `Xml` to get the table like... this

```
var pageTxt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(target).getContentText();
var pageDoc = Xml.parse(pageTxt,true);
var table = pageDoc.getElement().body.div.table
```

`Xml` is deprecated.

```
function myFunction() {
  var rss = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcurrent&CIK=&type=8-k&company=&dateb=&owner=include&start=0&count=40&output=atom"
  var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(rss).getContentText()
  var doc = XmlService.parse(r)
  var atom = XmlService.getNamespace(rss)
  var table = doc.getRootElement().getChildren('summary', atom)

}
```

Now I'm trying to use `XmlService` and having trouble getting that same table

Can some one help with the code to get the table? I need an array to loop through and go through each `tr` and `td`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from `entry` of the XML data and want to put the values to the Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw the data from the URL of `https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcurrent&CIK=&type=8-k&company=&dateb=&owner=include&start=0&count=40&output=atom`, I confirmed that the data is the XML data.
- When I saw your script, it seems that `entry` is not retrieved.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Retrieve the XML data from URL.
  var rss = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcurrent&CIK=&type=8-k&company=&dateb=&owner=include&start=0&count=40&output=atom"
  var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(rss).getContentText()

  // Parse the XML data.
  var doc = XmlService.parse(r)
  var root = doc.getRootElement();
  var ns = root.getNamespace();
  var entries = root.getChildren("entry", ns);
  var header = ["title", "link", "summary", "updated", "id"];
  var ar = entries.map(e => header.map(f => e.getChild(f, ns).getValue().trim()));
  ar.unshift(header);
  
  // Put the value to the active sheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
}
```

- When you want to retrieve only `summary`, please modify `var header = ["title", "link", "summary", "updated", "id"];` to `var header = ["summary"];`

#### Note:

- I thought that in your situation, the built-in formula of `IMPORTXML` can be also used, in this case, how about the following formula?

  ```
    =IMPORTXML("https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcurrent&CIK=&type=8-k&company=&dateb=&owner=include&start=0&count=40&output=atom","//*[local-name()='entry']")
  ```
- Or, when you want to retrieve the values of `summary`, you can also use the following formula.

  ```
    =IMPORTXML("https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcurrent&CIK=&type=8-k&company=&dateb=&owner=include&start=0&count=40&output=atom","//*[local-name()='summary']")
  ```

#### References:

- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)
- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: It seems that your code doesn't grab the `link` ... every one of those is blank. How do you get the `href` into your link column?

Comment: @jason Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In that case, about my sample script, please modify `var ar = entries.map(e => header.map(f => e.getChild(f, ns).getValue().trim()));` to `var ar = entries.map(e => header.map(f => f == "link" ? e.getChild(f, ns).getAttribute("href").getValue() : e.getChild(f, ns).getValue().trim()));`, and test it again.

Comment: Works now. So weird. I think it was working before. SEC must have changed it? Thanks for updating it.

Comment: @jason Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.